# ggplot Overlay Plot Figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data=data.frame("class"=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                "group"=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                "students"=c(23,31,29,27,28,40,20,23,39,25))
```

[image]

This is my data but for the life of me I can't generate this type of figure. I hope for class to be on the x axis, group to be the color, and the y-axis to be the student counts.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = class, y=students, fill = group)) +            
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = "identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

d = spread(data, group, students)
ggplot() +
    geom_col(data = d, aes(class, `1`), fill = "red", width = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_col(data = d, aes(class + 3, `2`), fill = "blue", width = 1,
             alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(20))
```

Update

```
library(data.table)
d = dcast(as.data.table(data), class ~ group, value.var = "students")
d$grp1 = "g1"
d$grp2 = "g2"

ggplot() +
    geom_col(data = d, aes(class, `1`, fill = grp1), width = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_col(data = d, aes(class + 3, `2`, fill = grp2), width = 1,
             alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(20)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(3, 6), labels = 1:2) +
    labs(fill = "grp")
```

Comment: excellent! is there data.table version of d = spread(data, group, students)

Comment: how do I add legend?